# Slow write performance on internal SSD disk

Tags: linux, debian, ssd, performance

=================

I am facing the following issue:

my SSD **Samsung EVO 850** is leaving me with terribly **slow write** performance.

I am getting only approx. **150 MB/s**, many times it is worse than that. I would expect much more higher write output.

```
dd if=debian-8.2.0-amd64-CD-1.iso of=testfile bs=1M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc

627+0 records in
627+0 records out
657457152 bytes (657 MB) copied, 4.31444 s, 152 MB/s
```

What I have on my system:

- linux - Debian - 7.9
- with kernel version: 
  Linux 3.10.0-13-pve #1 SMP Fri Oct 9 11:36:12 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- with Proxmox installed on it with version 3.4-166

I don't know how to see where the issue might be. Using tools like **iostat, iotop, dstat, strace** did not help at all. I am still stuck.

Any piece of advise really appreciated. Should I analyse that with tool like **systemtap**?

See please output of **lspci** command.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5520 I/O Hub to ESI Port (rev 13)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 13)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 13)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 13)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 13)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 13)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 13)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 13)
00:08.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev 13)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev 13)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 10 (rev 13)
00:0d.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 343a (rev 13)
00:0d.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 343b (rev 13)
00:0d.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 343c (rev 13)
00:0d.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 343d (rev 13)
00:0d.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 Physical Layer Port 0 (rev 13)
00:0d.5 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500 Physical Layer Port 1 (rev 13)
00:0d.6 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 341a (rev 13)
00:0e.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 341c (rev 13)
00:0e.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 341d (rev 13)
00:0e.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 341e (rev 13)
00:0e.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 341f (rev 13)
00:0e.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3439 (rev 13)
00:14.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub System Management Registers (rev 13)
00:14.1 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub GPIO and Scratch Pad Registers (rev 13)
00:14.2 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Control Status and RAS Registers (rev 13)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 5
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIB (ICH10) LPC Interface Controller
01:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI ES1000 (rev 02)
02:00.0 System peripheral: Hewlett-Packard Company Integrated Lights-Out Standard Slave Instrumentation & System Support (rev 04)
02:00.2 System peripheral: Hewlett-Packard Company Integrated Lights-Out Standard Management Processor Support and Messaging (rev 04)
02:00.4 USB controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Integrated Lights-Out Standard Virtual USB Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
05:00.0 RAID bus controller: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array G6 controllers (rev 01)
06:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS2308 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 (rev 05)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb NIC (rev 02)
09:00.1 Ethernet controller: Emulex Corporation OneConnect 10Gb NIC (rev 02)
3e:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3e:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3e:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3e:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3e:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 0 (rev 02)
3e:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 1 (rev 02)
3e:02.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
3e:02.5 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 1 (rev 02)
3e:03.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Registers (rev 02)
3e:03.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
3e:03.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller RAS Registers (rev 02)
3e:03.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers (rev 02)
3e:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control (rev 02)
3e:04.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address (rev 02)
3e:04.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank (rev 02)
3e:04.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
3e:05.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control (rev 02)
3e:05.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address (rev 02)
3e:05.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank (rev 02)
3e:05.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
3e:06.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Control (rev 02)
3e:06.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Address (rev 02)
3e:06.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Rank (rev 02)
3e:06.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Thermal Control (rev 02)
3f:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
3f:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 0 (rev 02)
3f:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 1 (rev 02)
3f:02.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
3f:02.5 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 1 (rev 02)
3f:03.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Registers (rev 02)
3f:03.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
3f:03.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller RAS Registers (rev 02)
3f:03.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers (rev 02)
3f:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control (rev 02)
3f:04.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address (rev 02)
3f:04.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank (rev 02)
3f:04.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
3f:05.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control (rev 02)
3f:05.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address (rev 02)
3f:05.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank (rev 02)
3f:05.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
3f:06.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Control (rev 02)
3f:06.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Address (rev 02)
3f:06.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Rank (rev 02)
3f:06.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Thermal Control (rev 02)
```

Comment: Have you tried different `bs` values >= 4M? Do you still get the same performance? (see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220652/is-dd-command-taking-too-long))

Comment: thanks. I tried to put various values for block size (bs) but I am getting the same result. Yet, very important thing I forgot to mention is I am using ext4 file system with the following mount options: rw,relatime,discard,nobarrier,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered.

Comment: Not en expert on this... so I am googling it. I see that `relatime` is good if you dont want to lose data. `nobarrier` seems a bit dangerous [here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/how-safe-is-nobarrier-and-ext4-huge-fsync-performance-difference.17717/) but improves your IO. `discard` ... I have no clue!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you posted, your motherboard has an ICH10 chipset, which is SATA II. So you should be getting read/write around 250/270 or so, close to half the rating of the SSD, which is SATA III. That is what I get on my iMac with the same chipset and a Samsung Pro.  Don't expect much more than this.

I am not a Linux expert, but just so you know the limitations of the X58 with ICH10.